# Why hyperbolic shapes of colour distortion in this image?

Tags: visible-light, camera

I took a photo of my computer screen through my mobile phone camera. Why are these color distortions in hyperbolic shape?

[image]

Comment: That is a good question.  Try taking photos from different distances.  I suspect that you're rmseeing Moire fringes, but the way the fringe pattern changes with distance from camera to computer screen will confirm or refute that guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a saddle in this picture of a computer screen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/417927/why-do-i-see-a-saddle-in-this-picture-of-a-computer-screen)