# Why is there this kind of contour pattern in a photo?

Tags: electromagnetism

Sometimes I take photos of my computer monitor with a smartphone. Then, when I try to zoom in to the picture of the monitor in the gallery of my phone, I start to see this pattern.

I am not sure if this is really just moire pattern. I mean, after I have taken the picture, I go to the gallery, look at the picture and change the zoom. As I start to change the zoom, I start to see random contouring pattern changing rapidly and changing shape, they look like something like below.

[image]

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I see a saddle in this picture of a computer screen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417927/)

Comment: @NiharKarve The pattern changes rapidly when I change the zoom after taking the picture.